# Convert array of string to array of double

Tags: c#, arrays, string, file, double

I have a text file (.txt)
with some decimal number :

```
0.3125
0.3
0.181818181818182
0.333333333333333
0.210526315789474
0.181818181818182
```

and I want to take these number to array of double. Here's my code :

```
double[] f1 = Convert.ToDouble(File.ReadLines("decimal list.txt").ToArray());
```

But I get and error of

> Cannot implicity convert type 'double' to 'double[]'

Comment: There is no overload of `Convert.ToDouble` that takes `double[]` as a parameter. You might need to read your text file line by line and try to parse each value.

Comment: How about a `.Select`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File.ReadLines("decimal list.txt")
    .Select(l => Convert.ToDouble(l))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: @GrantWinney Thanks, indeed it is.

Answer (score 9):

You can use ***Linq***:

```
  Double fi[] = File.ReadLines("list of stopword.txt")
                    .Select(x => Double.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because you are trying to assign a `double`(`Convert.ToDouble`) to a `double[]` variable. Instead you have to parse every line to double and create an array.

You can use LINQ:

```
double value = 0;
double[] f1 = File.ReadLines("decimal list.txt")
    .Where(l => double.TryParse(l.Trim(), out value))  // skips invalid lines
    .Select(l => value)
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The only `Convert.ToDouble` overload that matches is the [one that receives `Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55.aspx). This function, like all the other `ToDouble` overloads, returns `double`.

```
public static double ToDouble(
    Object value
)
```

You are therefore attempting to assign a `double` to a `double[]` and the compiler tells you that it cannot do so.

Of course, if you ever did pass your `string[]` array to that `Convert.ToDouble` overload it would fail with a runtime error because `Convert.ToDouble` expects to receive a single value, and return a single value. It simply does not convert multiple values in a single call.

What you need to do is convert each line from the file into a double. An effective way to do that would be to use a Linq query as demonstrated by various other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the string array and use Double.Parse or Double.TryParse (if you might have strings that won't parse as doubles in the array).

Answer (score 0):

Something like (not tested):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("decimal list.txt");
List<doulbe> values = new List<double>();

foreach(string line in lines)
{
    double value;

    if (double.TryParse(line, out value))
    {
        values.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because Convert.ToDouble returns a single double-precision value and you have double[] (array of double-precision variables) on the left side.

Try instead:

```
List<double> list = new List<double>();
foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("list of stopword.txt"))
  list.Add(double.Parse(line));
```